# XCeed Datagrid Binding twoWay

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, xceed-datagrid, xceed

I have a problem with the XCeed tool for advanced Datagrid with WPF.
I've create a datagrid bind on an observableCollection of objects and it works (objects become lines of the datagrid).
But The binding is only in OneWay and i don't know why. 
Do you have any idea ?

P.S : i have choose twoway mode everywhere and readonly property is false on all the component of the datagrid (and the datagrid itself)